# What exaclty are scopes in devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Sorry for stupid question, but what exactly are scopes in devise? Problem I run into is that I want to add sign_out method to my controller, and I can't do it because config.sign_out_all_scopes is set to true by default, so changing it to false would help, but I don't understand what this config actually does. It looks like being true it will sign out all :admins or all :users by signing out one, but it doesn't make sense to me. Is "scope" actually a user? What exactly will change if I toggle this option?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Devise allows you to separate your users into different "scopes" such as "admin" and "member", the effect of this is that you get a set of routes, controllers and views for each scope.

A user can belong to multiple scopes and sign in to any/all of them at any time - so when the option `sign_out_all_scopes` is true, signing out as any scope will sign out all of that users currently signed in scopes.

Regarding your specific question - why are you defining your own sign out method? Devise provides one for you. If you want to modify the sign out method make sure you follow [the instructions](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers) for properly extending the devise controllers.

Comment: What I wanted to do is to add something to add a sign_out method to my function in controller, that will sign out a person before a redirect, but using the default
sign_out :user         # sign_out(scope)
sign_out @user         # sign_out(resource)

end up with "wrong number of arguments"